# Read dynamic xml using element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Environment: Windows,Python,wxpython and Element tree as xml parser.

I am developing a stand alone where it reads the xml and creates a tree.
My application reads the xml and creates tree but when xml changes next time(when DEPTH of xml increases- i mean when two child elements are added).Application fails to read(Logic fails :( )

For e.g.
I have written a logic which can read any xml which has a depth of 5.But when it reads an xml with a depth more than 5 , it fails.
Please let me know how to read xml whose depth is dynamic.

Comment: Sounds like the problem may be in your logic, why don't you post it?

Comment: @ Robert Kluin.  Hi,I have added my sample code in the following gist with different depth.Please find it here - http://gist.github.com/643697. (gist: 643697). My code can read sample xml1 but fails to read sample xml 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use recursive calls, something more like:

```
def recurse_tree(node):
    tree = {}
    for element in node:
        name = element.get('name')
        tree[name] = recurse_tree(element)
    if tree:
        return tree
    else:
        return 'No children.'
```

Not all of your elements had 'name' attributes.   So you will need to adjust this to match your exact data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Xml which i had uploaded was a dummy.In my application,each element will have 'name' attribute.